# Extract content within a tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to extract the content `Hello world`. Please note that there are multiples `<table>` and similar `<td colspan="2">` on the page as well:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" width="800">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><b>Name: </b>Hello world</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
...
```

I tried the following:

```
hello = soup.find(text='Name: ')
hello.findPreviousSiblings
```

But it returned nothing.

In addition, I'm also having problem with the following extracting the `My home address`:

```html
<td><b>Address:</b></td>

<td>My home address</td>
```

I'm also using the same method to search for the `text="Address: "` but how do I navigate down to the next line and extract the content of `<td>`?

Answer (score 51):

The `contents` operator works well for extracting `text` from `<tag>text</tag>` .

---

`<td>My home address</td>` example:

```
s = '<td>My home address</td>'
soup =  BeautifulSoup(s)
td = soup.find('td') #<td>My home address</td>
td.contents #My home address
```

---

`<td><b>Address:</b></td>` example:

```
s = '<td><b>Address:</b></td>'
soup =  BeautifulSoup(s)
td = soup.find('td').find('b') #<b>Address:</b>
td.contents #Address:
```

Answer (score 21):

use next instead

```
>>> s = '<table border="0" cellspacing="2" width="800"><tr><td colspan="2"><b>Name: </b>Hello world</td></tr><tr>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> hello = soup.find(text='Name: ')
>>> hello.next
u'Hello world'
```

*next* and *previous* let you move through the document elements in the order they were processed by the parser while sibling methods work with the parse tree

Comment: It returns nothing.
hello = soup.find(text='Name: ')
hello.next

Comment: does 'Name:' appear anywhere else in the document?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments as i didn't know the return key actually posted the comment. I was thinking if there's a better method to do this just in case if there's a similar text which is "Name: ".

Comment: you can check for hello.parent.parent.name or hello.parent.parent.attrs or anything else you can latch onto

Comment: Do you mind giving a short example to illustrate parent.parent.name?

Comment: >>> hello.parent.parent.name 

    u'td' 

    >>> hello.parent.parent.name == 'td' 

    True 
 

 use that as a condition

Answer (score 6):

Use the below code to get extract text and content from html tags with python beautifulSoup

```
s = '<td>Example information</td>' # your raw html
soup =  BeautifulSoup(s) #parse html with BeautifulSoup
td = soup.find('td') #tag of interest <td>Example information</td>
td.text #Example information # clean text from html
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I decided to use .text since the user wanted to extract plain text from the html. After the user parses the the html with the Beautiful soup python library, he can use 'id', "class" or any other identifier to find the tag or html element of interest and after doing this, if he wants plain text within any of the selected tag, he can use .text on the tag as I decribed above

Answer (score 3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

def get_tag_html(tag: Tag):
    return ''.join([i.decode() if type(i) is Tag else i for i in tag.contents])
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)