# Retrieve content from from a tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

In one of my previous posts, I was able to retrieve all p tags

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import  urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url='https://www.centralpark.com/things-to-do/central-park-zoo/polar-bears/'
# opening up connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
# close connection
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, features="html.parser")

ps=list(page_soup.find_all('p'))

for s in ps:
    print(s)
```

What I want is to retrieve any content within those p tags.
Ex:

```
ex1='<p> this is example </p>' -> I want res1 = 'this is example' 
ex2='<p> this is <strong> nice </strong> example </p>' -> I want res2 = 'this is nice example' 
ex3='<p> this is <b> okeyish </b> example </p>' -> I want res3 = 'this is okeyish example'
```

All results(res1,res2,res3) may go to List.

I've searched for solutions, but solutions suggested just work for one type of tag [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/beautifulsoup-extract-content-within-a-tag). What I want is just retrieve ALL content between p and /p, no matter which other tags appear in between. If those other tags have content, those also should be included.

Comment: Use the .text attribute. So in stead of just, ‘print(s)’ do ‘print (s.text)’ and I believe that should get you going by just dumping each s.text into a results list. Also, when you do page_soup.find_all you dont need to have to tell it to return a list. It should do that already.

Comment: I tried to work with text too, but returns exceptions. Can you please reproduce above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps=page_soup.find_all('p')

results = []
for s in ps:
    #print(s.text)
    results = results.append(s.text)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'