# Python BeautifulSoup - get values from p

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
html = '<p class="product-new-price">96<sup>33</sup> <span class="tether-target tether-enabled tether-element-attached-top tether-element-attached-left tether-target-attached-top tether-target-attached-right">Lei</span>
</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

sup_elem = soup.find("sup").string # 33 - it works
```

How do I get the "96" before the  element ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract content within a tag with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: do you want to extent whole text inside p tag or text directly under 9 tag? How about text 'Lei' in given string?

Comment: Out of all the html I am interested just in 96.33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the previousSibling tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p class="product-new-price">96<sup>33</sup> <span class="tether-target tether-enabled tether-element-attached-top tether-element-attached-left tether-target-attached-top tether-target-attached-right">Lei</span>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

elem1 = soup.find("sup").previousSibling
elem2 = soup.find("sup").text # 33 - it works

print ('.'.join([elem1, elem2]))
```

**Output:**

```
96.33
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use children method. It will return a list of all the children of p tag. (6 will be first child of it.

```
html = '<p class="product-new-price">96<sup>33</sup> <span class="tether-target tether-enabled tether-element-attached-top tether-element-attached-left tether-target-attached-top tether-target-attached-right">Lei</span>
</p>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

elem = list(soup.find("p").children)[0] #0th element of the list will be 96
sup_elem = soup.find("sup").string

result = elem + '.' + sup_elem #96.33
```

Answer (score 1):

Use select instead.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p class="product-new-price">96<sup>33</sup> <span class="tether-target tether-enabled tether-element-attached-top tether-element-attached-left tether-target-attached-top tether-target-attached-right">Lei</span>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.product-new-price').text.strip().replace('Lei',''))
```

There is no "." in source but you can always divide by 100

```
print(int(soup.select_one('.product-new-price').text.strip().replace('Lei',''))/100)
```

Comment: your output is 9633 and it should be 96.33

Comment: there is no "." in the source.

Comment: If you want one just do print(int(soup.select_one('.product-new-price').text.strip().replace('Lei',''))/100)