# How to elicit a word from list (python)

Tags: python

**I have a list where every element (str) look like this** (downloaded from site using request and bs4):

```
<div align="justify" class="textdiv">
<p><strong>А</strong></p><p>     А,  союз.  1.  Соединяет  предложения  или  члены  предложения, выражаяпротивопоставление, сопоставление. Он поехал, а я остался. Пиши ручкой, а некарандашом.  Красив,  а не  умен. ....
```

I need to elicit **A** word (between <"strong>") and add this word in another list. I have no idea how to do it, could you help me? Thank you

Comment: Use a html parser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract content within a tag with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 2):

Use `BeautifulSoup`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = ['<div align="justify" class="textdiv"><p><strong>А</strong></p><p>     А,  союз.  1.  Соединяет  предложения  или  члены  предложения, выражаяпротивопоставление, сопоставление. Он поехал, а я остался. Пиши ручкой, а некарандашом.  Красив,  а не  умен. ....']
for i in data:
    s = BeautifulSoup(i, "html.parser")
    strong = s.find("strong")
    if strong:   #Check if strong tag present in html
        print(strong.text)   #get text
```

**Output:**

```
А
```

Comment: That is an indentation error. always use 4 space when coding in python.