# How to extract json from script tag using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the `reviewCount` from the script tag using beautiful soup. Tried different approach but didn't succeed.

```
<script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-filter">
{"languages":[{"isoCode":"all","displayName":"Toutes les langues","reviewCount":"573"},{"isoCode":"fr","displayName":"français","reviewCount":"567"},{"isoCode":"en","displayName":"English","reviewCount":"6"}],"selectedLanguages":["all"],"selectedStars":null,"selectedLocationId":null}
</script>
```

Comment: _Tried different approach but didn't succeed._ Can you share those attempts? From the tag you shared, at seems that all you need to do is get the contents of the tag and parse the result. If you're struggling with extracting the content from the element, this is a duplicate of [Extract content within a tag with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup). If the issue is parsing the JSON, this is a duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-json-in-python).

Answer (score 9):

This should work, I am absolutely sure there is a more elegant approach:

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-filter">
{"languages":[{"isoCode":"all","displayName":"Toutes les langues","reviewCount":"573"},{"isoCode":"fr","displayName":"français","reviewCount":"567"},{"isoCode":"en","displayName":"English","reviewCount":"6"}],"selectedLanguages":["all"],"selectedStars":null,"selectedLocationId":null}
</script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find('script')
json_object = json.loads(res.contents[0])

for language in json_object['languages']:
    print('{}: {}'.format(language['displayName'], language['reviewCount']))
```

output:

```
Toutes les langues: 573
français: 567
English: 6
```

Comment: Thanks James. I tried the method you mentioned above. My main problem is to get the reviewCount number.

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: `json.loads(res.text)` worked too for me

Answer (score 3):

Import json and load data into `json` and then iterarte to get all the `reviewCount`.

```
import json
html='''<script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-filter">
{"languages":[{"isoCode":"all","displayName":"Toutes les langues","reviewCount":"573"},{"isoCode":"fr","displayName":"français","reviewCount":"567"},{"isoCode":"en","displayName":"English","reviewCount":"6"}],"selectedLanguages":["all"],"selectedStars":null,"selectedLocationId":null}
</script>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
item=soup.select_one('script[data-initial-state="review-filter"]').text
jsondata=json.loads(item)
for item in jsondata['languages']:
    print(item['reviewCount'])
```

**Output**:

```
573
567
6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

html = '''<script type="application/json" data-initial-state="review-filter">
{"languages":[{"isoCode":"all","displayName":"Toutes les langues","reviewCount":"573"},{"isoCode":"fr","displayName":"français","reviewCount":"567"},{"isoCode":"en","displayName":"English","reviewCount":"6"}],"selectedLanguages":["all"],"selectedStars":null,"selectedLocationId":null}
</script>'''


match = [item.group(1) for item in re.finditer('reviewCount":"(.+?)"', html)]

print(match)
```

Output:

```
['573', '567', '6']
```