# How do I get value of tags while scraping a website with python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website, here's the HTML code

```
<h2>Information</h2>
<div>
  <span class="dark_text">Type:</span>
  <a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=tv">TV</a>
</div>
<div class="spaceit">
  <span class="dark_text">Episodes:</span>
  12
</div>
<div class="spaceit">
  <span class="dark_text">Duration:</span>
  25 min. per ep.
</div>
```

and I'm trying to get `Episodes:` & `12` and `Duration:` & `25 min. per ep.` and a lot more like this in the full html code.

I wanted these values as string

my python code is

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

spaceit = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class": "spaceit"})
```

I'm unable to figure out how to find the values of `span` and `div`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? There is plenty of information available on BeautifulSoup, what makes this situation special? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Use select then run for loop*

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<h2>Information</h2>' \
       '<div>' \
       '<span class="dark_text">Type:</span>' \
       '<a href="https://myanimelist.net/topanime.php?type=tv">TV</a>' \
       '</div>' \
       '<div class="spaceit">' \
       '<span class="dark_text">Episodes:</span>12</div>' \
       '<div class="spaceit">' \
       '<span class="dark_text">Duration:</span>25 min. per ep.</div> '

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
elements = page_soup.select('div.spaceit')

for element in elements:
    print(element.get_text())
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know what to Google to find the get_text() function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element