# Convert multipule HTML to CSV file quickly in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to extract data from multipule html files and convert them to single csv file. As the html page is absolutely unstructured, the task become tedious. Once I finished the task, the test run goes well for 1, 2 .... 10 files but after that, it starts taking long time. For 100+ files it nearly collapses. I tried 340 files. It worked but took at least 3 hours and the machine got hang at the end. Pasting the full code below with attachment to the example of html file (source code). Is there any better way to process? 
Note: I have already checked [this answer](https://github.com/sangharshbyss/EcourtsData/blob/master/samplePage.html) and it doesn't help much. Thanks.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import glob
import datetime

root_dir = r'/home/some path'
all_list = []
for newFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '**/*.html'), recursive=True):
    dictionary = {}
    # create soup.
    openFile = open(newFile)
    soup = bs(openFile, 'html.parser')
    # section 1: Case Details
    try:
        caseType = soup.find('span', {'class': 'case_details_table'})
        caseTypeChild = caseType.findChild()
        # ref for .next - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup
        sessionsCase = caseTypeChild.next.next.next
        filing = sessionsCase.next.next
        filingNumberHeading = filing.find('label')
        filingNumber = filingNumberHeading.next.next
        filingDate = filingNumber.next.next.next.next
        registration = filingDate.next.next
        registrationNumberHeading = registration.find('label')
        registrationNumber = registrationNumberHeading.next.next.next
        cnrHeading = soup.find('b').find('label')
        cnrNumber = cnrHeading.next.next
        dictionary['Filing Number'] = filingNumber
        dictionary['Filing Date'] = filingDate
        dictionary['Registration Number'] = registrationNumber
        dictionary['CNR Number'] = cnrNumber
    except:
        pass

    # section 2: Case Status
    try:
        firstHearing = soup.find('strong')
        firstHearingDate = firstHearing.next_sibling.text
        dictionary['First Hearing'] = firstHearingDate
        nextHearing = soup.find('strong', text='Next Hearing Date')
        nextHearingDate = nextHearing.next_sibling.text
        dictionary['Next Hearing'] = nextHearingDate
        stageOfCase = soup.find('strong', text='Stage of Case')
        stageOfCaseText = stageOfCase.next_sibling.text
        dictionary['Stage of Case'] = stageOfCaseText
        courtNumber = soup.find('strong', text='Court Number and Judge')
        courtNumberText = courtNumber.next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip()
        dictionary['Court Number and Judge'] = courtNumberText
    except:
        pass

    # section 6: FIR Details
    try:
        policeStationHeading = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'FIR_details_table'}).next.next
        policeStation = policeStationHeading.next.next.next.next
        firnumberHeading = policeStation.next.next.next
        firNumber = policeStation.find_next('label').next
        firYearHeading = firNumber.next.next.next
        firYear = firNumber.find_next('span').find_next('label').next
        # same as previous sections.
        dictionary[policeStationHeading] = policeStation
        dictionary[firnumberHeading] = firNumber
        dictionary[firYearHeading] = firYear
    except:
        pass

    # section 3: Petioner and Advocate
    try:
        petitioner = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'Petitioner_Advocate_table'})
        petitionerName = petitioner.next
        dictionary['Name of the Petitioner'] = petitionerName
        petitionerAdvocate = petitionerName.next.next
        dictionary['Name of the Advocate'] = petitionerAdvocate
    # section 4: Respondent and Advocate
        respondent = petitionerAdvocate.find_next('span')
        respondentName = respondent.next
        dictionary['Name of the Respondent'] = respondentName
    except:
        pass
    # section 5: Acts
    '''In this section 1. soup is prepared from act_table tab of web page
    2. Keys for main dictionary are created defining headings of acts. with 'not applied' values. 
    3. short form variables are created for names of the act. 
    4. list of acts is compared with list of variables and sections are replaced as values in the dictionary. '''

    acts = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(1)')
    sections = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(2)')
    dictionary['IPC'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['PoA'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['PCSO'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['PCR'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['Any Other Act'] = 'Not Applied'

    ipc = 'indian penal code'
    poa = 'prevention of atrocities'
    pcso = 'protection of children from sexual'
    pcr = 'protection of civil rights'


    try:
        act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
        sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
        string = str(act1)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        act2 = tuple(acts[1].contents)
        sections2 = tuple(sections[1].contents)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        act3 = tuple(acts[2].contents)
        sections3 = tuple(sections[2].contents)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        act4 = tuple(acts[3].contents)
        sections4 = tuple(sections[3].contents)
    except:
        pass
    # using if and not for loop then actSession is not needed
    # for first act in list
    if len(acts) < 2:
        if ipc in string.lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
        elif poa in string.lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
        elif pcso in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
        elif pcr in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
        else:
            pass
    # for 2nd act in list
    elif len(acts) == 2:
        if ipc in string.lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
        elif poa in string.lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
        elif pcso in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
        else:
            pass
        if ipc in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
        elif poa in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
        elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
        else:
            pass
    # for 3rd act in list
    elif len(acts) == 3:
        if ipc in string.lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
        elif poa in string.lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
        elif pcso in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
        elif pcr in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
        else:
            pass
        if ipc in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
        elif poa in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
        elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
        elif pcr in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PCR'] = sections2
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    all_list.append(dictionary)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_list)
df = df[['CNR Number', 'Filing Number', 'Filing Date', 'First Hearing', 'Next Hearing', 'Stage of Case', 'Registration Number', 'Year', 'FIR Number', 'Police Station', 'Court Number and Judge',  'PoA', 'IPC', 'PCR', 'PCSO', 'Any Other Act', 'Name of the Petitioner', 'Name of the Advocate', 'Name of the Respondent']]
outputFile = open(os.path.join('/home/some path name/ file + str(
    datetime.datetime.now().day) + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().month) + '_' + str(
    datetime.datetime.now().year) + '.csv'), 'w')
df.to_csv(outputFile)
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) ? It loads all `html` tables into a list of datafram

Comment: @AlexandreB. Thanks. Tried but then the page is very unstructured. It has few tables. so it becomes difficult to extract data with pd. read

Comment: Maybe can you share a sample of your data ? It's quite difficult to go into a such a long code without having a whole overview. Also, I think you're more likely to have responses on the [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum than *stackoverflow*.

Comment: You pull all of the data into `all_list` and then write at the end with a dataframe - so all data is held in memory. Instead, you could ditch all_list and pandas, use csv.DictWriter and write row at a time.

Comment: @tdelaney I will try that and update you. Can you convert your comment to answer please, if that is suitable?

Comment: @sangharsh - I'm happy to do that. I'm not sure if its the whole problem, but its a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save all of the csv rows to a list of dictionaries and only use `pandas` at the end to build the CSV file. Instead of holding all of the data in memory, you could use `csv.DictWriter` to write the csv file one row at a time.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import glob
import datetime

csv_header = ['CNR Number', 'Filing Number', 'Filing Date', 'First Hearing', 'Next Hearing', 'Stage of Case', 'Registration Number', 'Year', 'FIR Number', 'Police Station', 'Court Number and Judge',  'PoA', 'IPC', 'PCR', 'PCSO', 'Any Other Act', 'Name of the Petitioner', 'Name of the Advocate', 'Name of the Respondent']

root_dir = r'/home/some path'

def convert_html_case_files_to_csv():

    output_filename = os.path.join('/home/some path name/ file' + str(
        datetime.datetime.now().day) + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().month) + '_' + str(
        datetime.datetime.now().year) + '.csv')

    with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
        for newFile in glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '**/*.html'), recursive=True):
            writer.writerow(process_case_file(newFile)

def process_case_file(filename):
    """Read and parse html file, return csv row as dict"""
    dictionary = {}
    # create soup.
    openFile = open(newFile)
    soup = bs(openFile, 'html.parser')
    # section 1: Case Details
    try:
        caseType = soup.find('span', {'class': 'case_details_table'})
        caseTypeChild = caseType.findChild()
        # ref for .next - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup
        sessionsCase = caseTypeChild.next.next.next
        filing = sessionsCase.next.next
        filingNumberHeading = filing.find('label')
        filingNumber = filingNumberHeading.next.next
        filingDate = filingNumber.next.next.next.next
        registration = filingDate.next.next
        registrationNumberHeading = registration.find('label')
        registrationNumber = registrationNumberHeading.next.next.next
        cnrHeading = soup.find('b').find('label')
        cnrNumber = cnrHeading.next.next
        dictionary['Filing Number'] = filingNumber
        dictionary['Filing Date'] = filingDate
        dictionary['Registration Number'] = registrationNumber
        dictionary['CNR Number'] = cnrNumber
    except:
        pass

    # section 2: Case Status
    try:
        firstHearing = soup.find('strong')
        firstHearingDate = firstHearing.next_sibling.text
        dictionary['First Hearing'] = firstHearingDate
        nextHearing = soup.find('strong', text='Next Hearing Date')
        nextHearingDate = nextHearing.next_sibling.text
        dictionary['Next Hearing'] = nextHearingDate
        stageOfCase = soup.find('strong', text='Stage of Case')
        stageOfCaseText = stageOfCase.next_sibling.text
        dictionary['Stage of Case'] = stageOfCaseText
        courtNumber = soup.find('strong', text='Court Number and Judge')
        courtNumberText = courtNumber.next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip()
        dictionary['Court Number and Judge'] = courtNumberText
    except:
        pass

    # section 6: FIR Details
    try:
        policeStationHeading = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'FIR_details_table'}).next.next
        policeStation = policeStationHeading.next.next.next.next
        firnumberHeading = policeStation.next.next.next
        firNumber = policeStation.find_next('label').next
        firYearHeading = firNumber.next.next.next
        firYear = firNumber.find_next('span').find_next('label').next
        # same as previous sections.
        dictionary[policeStationHeading] = policeStation
        dictionary[firnumberHeading] = firNumber
        dictionary[firYearHeading] = firYear
    except:
        pass

    # section 3: Petioner and Advocate
    try:
        petitioner = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'Petitioner_Advocate_table'})
        petitionerName = petitioner.next
        dictionary['Name of the Petitioner'] = petitionerName
        petitionerAdvocate = petitionerName.next.next
        dictionary['Name of the Advocate'] = petitionerAdvocate
    # section 4: Respondent and Advocate
        respondent = petitionerAdvocate.find_next('span')
        respondentName = respondent.next
        dictionary['Name of the Respondent'] = respondentName
    except:
        pass
    # section 5: Acts
    '''In this section 1. soup is prepared from act_table tab of web page
    2. Keys for main dictionary are created defining headings of acts. with 'not applied' values. 
    3. short form variables are created for names of the act. 
    4. list of acts is compared with list of variables and sections are replaced as values in the dictionary. '''

    acts = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(1)')
    sections = soup.select('#act_table td:nth-of-type(2)')
    dictionary['IPC'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['PoA'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['PCSO'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['PCR'] = 'Not Applied'
    dictionary['Any Other Act'] = 'Not Applied'

    ipc = 'indian penal code'
    poa = 'prevention of atrocities'
    pcso = 'protection of children from sexual'
    pcr = 'protection of civil rights'


    try:
        act1 = tuple(acts[0].contents)
        sections1 = tuple(sections[0].contents)
        string = str(act1)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        act2 = tuple(acts[1].contents)
        sections2 = tuple(sections[1].contents)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        act3 = tuple(acts[2].contents)
        sections3 = tuple(sections[2].contents)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        act4 = tuple(acts[3].contents)
        sections4 = tuple(sections[3].contents)
    except:
        pass
    # using if and not for loop then actSession is not needed
    # for first act in list
    if len(acts) < 2:
        if ipc in string.lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
        elif poa in string.lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
        elif pcso in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
        elif pcr in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
        else:
            pass
    # for 2nd act in list
    elif len(acts) == 2:
        if ipc in string.lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
        elif poa in string.lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
        elif pcso in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
        else:
            pass
        if ipc in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
        elif poa in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
        elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
        else:
            pass
    # for 3rd act in list
    elif len(acts) == 3:
        if ipc in string.lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections1
        elif poa in string.lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections1
        elif pcso in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections1
        elif pcr in string.lower():
            dictionary['PCR'] = sections1
        else:
            pass
        if ipc in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['IPC'] = sections2
        elif poa in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PoA'] = sections2
        elif pcso in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PCSO'] = sections2
        elif pcr in str(act2).lower():
            dictionary['PCR'] = sections2
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    return dictionary

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def convert_html_case_files_to_csv()
```

I moved the work into functions to make it easy to experiment with multiprocessing. Because your work is fairly cpu-intensive, you may find a pool of workers gets the job done faster.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def convert_html_case_files_to_csv():

    output_filename = os.path.join('/home/some path name/ file' + str(
        datetime.datetime.now().day) + '_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().month) + '_' + str(
        datetime.datetime.now().year) + '.csv')
    # wilding guessing 4 processors sounds good...
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        with open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
            writer.writerows(pool.imap_unordered(process_case_file, 
                glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '**/*.html'), recursive=True)))
```

Comment: working on it. Once worked successfully, I will accept the answer. Thanks, with love.

Comment: Though I have accepted the answer, the multiple processing dose not work as suggested. I have not used multiple processing while working on my data as it throws recursion error.

Comment: @sangharsh - Sorry to hear that. I haven't spotted any recursive functions in your coe (except recursive=True in glob but that shouldn't be a problem). I can't really help ther.e

Answer (score 1):

The all_list dict is accumulating the data from all files. I recommend writing one row for each data extracts as follows

```
df = dictionary[['CNR Number', 'Filing Number', 'Filing Date', 'First Hearing', 'Next Hearing', 'Stage of Case', 'Registration Number', 'Year', 'FIR Number', 'Police Station', 'Court Number and Judge',  'PoA', 'IPC', 'PCR', 'PCSO', 'Any Other Act', 'Name of the Petitioner', 'Name of the Advocate', 'Name of the Respondent']]
one_case=''
for i in df:
    one_case=i+','
one_case=one_case+'\n'
outputFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
outputFile.write(one_case)
outputFile.close()
```

dict index are fixed therefore each case can be put in a seperate row and a comma seperated file can be appended for each processed html file.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with Danish courts once.

What I found was that the language in the matter was limited: Lawyer, Judge, defendant, case numbers, codes of this and that, but even if the content was structured much the same way, the courts used different templates and ways to present it, even if all the pages sort of looked the same.

So I first converted them to normal text with lxml (You can probably use soup for that too)

Then I used an array of regular expressions to take out the content I wanted and a primitive state machine to remember where I was when needed. I remember that I used forward lookup much

```
(?=...)
```

to ensure that I did not eat some of the next text I wanted to find.

It took time, but finally I got them all. Then "They" removed the possibility to do it and closed me down.

Informed citizens are not always happy.

Comment: i can understand why you have been down voted. You don't give any answer as such. Rather, you promote an view point in your answer. I appreciate that and so I up voted you. But really, need an answer!