# how to recover only the text of a <a> in webscraping in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to recover only the "A côté" in:

```
<a href="https://www.synonymeur.com/synonyme/a-cote/" title="Synonyme du mot À côté">À côté</a>
```

In python with beautifulsoup and requests.

Comment: Can you please show the (minimal) code you have used to get this string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract content within a tag with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999407/extract-content-within-a-tag-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

To find all  tag texts use following,

```
links = soup.find_all('a')
links_texts = [x.text for x in links]
```

In order to select certain tags use the "attrs" parameter in the soup.find_all function.